# AWS CDK Pipelines Creates Multiple Artifact Buckets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline

I'm having some trouble with CDK Pipeline/ CodePipeline in AWS. When I run the pipeline (git commit) the Assets section always runs even if I don't change the files that it is building and every pipeline execution creates an S3 bucket with pipeline assets so we have loads of s3 buckets. This behaviour while odd does seem to work but it takes a long time to run and doesn't seem right. Is this to be expected and if not what may be the issue?

**Update**
We sometimes see the below error msg in the build logs which may be related but it doesn't cause failure:

```
Failed to store notices in the cache: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/root/.cdk/cache/notices.json'
```

Comment: Please add a minimal example to illustrate.  The multiple S3 buckets problem is not expected.  Are you inadvertently changing resource names?  All pipeline stages, including the Asset stage, run each execution.  Pipelines are stateless, but do [have the option](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.pipelines-readme.html#customizing-codebuild-projects) to use CodeBuild [caching](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-caching.html).

Comment: Not sure how I could add a minimal example tbh but thanks for the comment that is helpful. We are naming all resources with a convention which reads a parameter from a config but it shouldn't be changing. But even if resource names did change, it should still use one bucket for assets right?

Comment: A minimal CDK pipeline that results in the described behavior would be helpful.

Comment: Buckets are \*not deleted\* by default when a Stack is destroyed.   This means you expect a new artefact bucket to be created each time you destroy/recreate the pipeline stack itself or rename the parent construct.  A new bucket per pipeline \*execution\*, however, is not expected.

Answer (score 0):

If you create an S3 bucket and then reference that bucket in your Codepipeline, the output will always be in that S3 bucket, and the artifacts will be sub directories of that specific S3 bucket. That way you will get new build assets, but they will be placed inside of the same bucket, and you only have one S3 bucket.